# Why does my bond have two ipv6 addresses?

Tags: linux, networking, systemd, systemd-networkd, bonding

You can see below, the bond has two ipv6 addresses, 2603:8080:4540:7cfb::13fc and 2603:8080:4540:7cfb:4866:4bff:fe44:a988. Which makes me think systemd-networkd is somehow failing to treat the bond as a single interface.

```
root@gentooserver /etc/systemd/network # networkctl
IDX LINK  TYPE      OPERATIONAL SETUP     
  1 lo    loopback  carrier     unmanaged
  2 eno1  ether     enslaved    configured
  3 eno2  ether     enslaved    configured
  4 bond1 bond      routable    configured
  5 wg0   wireguard routable    unmanaged

5 links listed.

root@gentooserver /etc/systemd/network # networkctl status bond1
● 4: bond1                                                                               
                     Link File: /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
                  Network File: /etc/systemd/network/master.network
                          Type: bond
                         State: routable (configured)
                  Online state: online                                                   
                        Driver: bonding
                    HW Address: 4a:66:4b:44:a9:88
                           MTU: 1500 (min: 68, max: 65535)
                         QDisc: noqueue
  IPv6 Address Generation Mode: eui64
                          Mode: 802.3ad
                        Miimon: 10s
                       Updelay: 20s
                     Downdelay: 1min 20s
          Queue Length (Tx/Rx): 16/16
              Auto negotiation: no
                         Speed: 1Gbps
                        Duplex: full
                       Address: 10.0.0.46 (DHCP4 via 10.0.0.1)
                                2603:8080:4540:7cfb::13fc
                                2603:8080:4540:7cfb:4866:4bff:fe44:a988
                                fe80::4866:4bff:fe44:a988
                       Gateway: 10.0.0.1
                                fe80::96de:80ff:fea8:8096 (GIGA-BYTE TECHNOLOGY CO.,LTD.)
                                fe80::a263:91ff:fe7c:32a2 (NETGEAR)
                           DNS: 10.0.0.1
                                2603:8080:4540:7cfb:96de:80ff:fea8:8096
                Search Domains: dehnel.info
              Carrier Bound To: eno1
                                eno2
             Activation Policy: bound
           Required For Online: yes
               DHCP4 Client ID: IAID:0x8db4800/DUID
             DHCP6 Client IAID: 0x8db4800
             DHCP6 Client DUID: DUID-EN/Vendor:0000ab11abc83a896377c51f0000

Sep 29 17:35:35 gentooserver systemd-networkd[2235623]: bond1: Link UP
Sep 29 17:35:35 gentooserver systemd-networkd[2235623]: bond1: Gained carrier
Sep 29 17:35:35 gentooserver systemd-networkd[2235623]: bond1: Lost carrier
Sep 29 17:35:35 gentooserver systemd-networkd[2235623]: bond1: DHCPv6 lease lost
Sep 29 17:35:35 gentooserver systemd-networkd[2235623]: bond1: Link DOWN
Sep 29 17:35:38 gentooserver systemd-networkd[2235623]: bond1: Link UP
Sep 29 17:35:38 gentooserver systemd-networkd[2235623]: bond1: Gained carrier
Sep 29 17:35:40 gentooserver systemd-networkd[2235623]: bond1: Gained IPv6LL
Sep 29 17:35:42 gentooserver systemd-networkd[2235623]: bond1: DHCPv4 address 10.0.0.46/24 via 10.0.0.1
Sep 29 17:35:43 gentooserver systemd-networkd[2235623]: bond1: DHCPv6 address 2603:8080:4540:7cfb::13fc/128 (valid for 2h, preferred for 1h 15min)

root@gentooserver /etc/systemd/network # tail *
==> bond1.netdev <==
Name=bond1
Kind=bond

[Bond]
Mode=802.3ad
MIIMonitorSec=1s
LACPTransmitRate=fast
TransmitHashPolicy=layer2
UpDelaySec=2s
DownDelaySec=8s

==> eno1.network <==
[Match]
Name=eno1

[Network]
Bond=bond1

==> eno2.network <==
[Match]
Name=eno2

[Network]
Bond=bond1

==> master.network <==
IPv6AcceptRA=yes

[Link]
Multicast=yes

[DHCPv4]
UseDomains=true

[IPv6AcceptRA]
UseDomains=yes

root@gentooserver /etc/systemd/network # ifconfig
bond1: flags=5187<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MASTER,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.46  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
        inet6 fe80::4866:4bff:fe44:a988  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2603:8080:4540:7cfb::13fc  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2603:8080:4540:7cfb:4866:4bff:fe44:a988  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 4a:66:4b:44:a9:88  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 179330571  bytes 26132404875 (24.3 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 914092  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1543646148  bytes 2313271455798 (2.1 TiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 5 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eno1: flags=6211<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SLAVE,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 4a:66:4b:44:a9:88  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2371371  bytes 200785874 (191.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 911837  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 60668  bytes 7644831 (7.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xfae00000-fae7ffff  

eno2: flags=6211<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SLAVE,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 4a:66:4b:44:a9:88  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 176959198  bytes 25931618869 (24.1 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 869  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1543585480  bytes 2313263810967 (2.1 TiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xfad00000-fad7ffff  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 3334928  bytes 580238437 (553.3 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3334928  bytes 580238437 (553.3 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wg0: flags=209<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1420
        inet 192.168.2.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  destination 192.168.2.1
        inet6 fd86:ea04:1111::1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 18363  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The ip's have the same MAC address, which makes me think the bond is working:

```
ip -6 neigh show | grep 2603:8080:4540:7cfb::13fc
2603:8080:4540:7cfb::13fc dev wlp170s0 lladdr 4a:66:4b:44:a9:88 router REACHABLE
ip -6 neigh show | grep 2603:8080:4540:7cfb:4866:4bff:fe44:a988
2603:8080:4540:7cfb:4866:4bff:fe44:a988 dev wlp170s0 lladdr 4a:66:4b:44:a9:88 router REACHABLE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your IPv6 prefix length is 64, so autonomous address configuration with SLAAC is possible. Apparently your IPv6 router advertisements allow both autonomous configuration and the use of DHCPv6.

You might want to run `rdisc6 -1 bond1` to view the contents of the router advertisements received by your system. The output will probably include lines like `Autonomous address conf.: Yes` (i.e. SLAAC address configuration enabled) and `Stateful address conf. : Yes` (DHCPv6 address configuration enabled).

This would result in two IPv6 addresses getting configured automatically for each interface - including the bond in this case. It is a valid configuration for IPv6, although perhaps not what you expected.

`2603:8080:4540:7cfb:4866:4bff:fe44:a988` seems to be an EUI64-style address generated from the MAC address and the prefix advertised by the router. It is identifiable by the ...`:xSxx:xxff:fexx:xxxx` format. The `x` digits come from the corresponding digits of the MAC address, and the S digit has its 2nd least significant bit inverted.

`2603:8080:4540:7cfb::13fc` must then be the address assigned by DHCPv6.